# Keeping only a list of certain columns in a very robust dataset?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do a few things with some longitudinal data:

1) Combine several years worth of data into one table
e.g.

```
data1996.csv,
data1997.csv,
...,
data2013.csv
```

2) Define a list of variables to keep

3) Drop all columns that do not match the list of keepers
4) Write the result dataset into a CSV file

```
require(data.table)
setwd("~/my/directory")
```

Define names of filepaths

```
paths <- list()
```

Make a list of the files I want to aggregate

```
for(i in 0:17) 
{
  paths[i]<- paste("MERGED",1996+i,"_PP.csv",sep="")
}
```

Define list of variables to keep

```
keeps <- list(
  "CITY",
  "ZIP",
  "LONGITUDE",
  "LATITUDE",
   ...
)
```

Run fread on all files in the list of paths

```
out <- rbindlist(lapply(paths, fread), use.names=TRUE)
```

For some reason typeof(out) returns list

This is where I attempt to drop all columns except those in "keeps"

```
filteredOut <- out[,keeps,drop=FALSE]
```

But it just gives me a list of the 28 variables I want to keep

I tried this too:

```
filteredOut <- out[keeps]
```

but I get this error:

```
  Error in `[.data.table`(out, keeps) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.
    write.table(filteredOut, "testing.csv", sep=",")
```

My script appears to successfully combine the 17 years of data (I end up with 'out' which has 117905 obs. in 1729 variables)

Afterwards, I want to save to a csv:

```
write.table(filteredOut, "myfile.csv", sep=",")
```

I do get warnings as well, over 50 of them but they appear to regard NULL values. The issues I am having are 1) understanding data types (list, data.frame, data.table) and 2) the proper way to implement the drop command

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In regards to your `list` type issue, remember that a `data.frame` is just a `list`, where each list item is the same length. See `is.list(data.frame(a=1))` and `unclass(data.frame(a=1,b=2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `unlist` the 'keeps', and use `with=FALSE` to subset the columns.

```
out[, unlist(keeps), with=FALSE]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I totally forgot something - in combining these csv's, I forgot to create a column with YEAR. Perhaps in my for loop I can do it. What do you suggest as the easiest way to add a YEAR variable when aggregating these CSVs?

Thanks again for your timely and concise help

Comment: @nAguirre Do you have `YEAR` as a vector or in other dataset?  If it is a vector `out[, unlist(keeps), with=FALSE][, YEAR:= YEAR]`

Comment: YEAR does not exist, I will have to add it in the for loop using (i+1996). I don't imagine I have to do this row-by-row? But I'm not sure how else. Perhaps I can pass a function in lapply that will set the year to whatever the paths index is + 1996??

Comment: @nAguirre Can I assume that you want to extract the YEAR from the file names i.e. `data1996.csv`

Comment: @nAguirre I think what you need is `files <- list.files(pattern='\\.csv'); out <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread) , idcol='Grp'); nm1 <- gsub('\\D+', '', files); out[, unlist(keeps), with=FALSE][, YEAR:= nm1[as.numeric(Grp)]]` (not tested)

Comment: I am getting this error:

> filteredOut <- out[, unlist(keeps), with=FALSE][, YEAR:= nm1[as.numeric(Grp)]]

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Grp' not found

Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation on SO to chat

Comment: @nAguirre DId you try with `idcol='Grp'` in `rbindlist`.  It is a new feature from `data.tablev1.9.6` onwards.  Can you tell me the data.table version you have?

Comment: I run ?data.table and it says at the bottom:

[Package data.table version 1.9.6 Index]

Comment: @naAguirre Just tested now.  Try `lst <- lapply(files, fread); nm1 <- gsub('\\D+', '', files);  names(lst) <- nm1; out <- rbindlist(lst, idcol=TRUE); out[, c(unlist(keeps) , '.id'), with=FALSE]`

Comment: @nAguirre  BTW, I used `files <- c('data1996.csv', 'data1997.csv'); nm1 <- gsub('\\D+', '', files);
nm1#[1] "1996" "1997"`

Comment: for some reason all of the headers were off by one. There was a column with the row numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4) and no column header, and then all other column headers were moved left one. This was a very quick fix in Excel though. I might have entered some of the code wrong as the YEAR column did not have a header (though it did have the appropriate years)

Comment: @nAguirre I tried on an example data and it is working though.

Comment: if you're using `fread`, why not pass your `keeps` vector to the `select` argument?